# makefile OR code blocks TO eclipse on ubuntu

Tags: c++, eclipse, makefile, codeblocks, openframeworks

hi i have a c++ opengl/opencv codeblocks project http://www.openframeworks.cc/setup/linux-codeblocks with all makefiles. even if codeblocks seems to be grat tool i'm addicted to eclipse (using it with python and java). is there a way to import it in eclipse without melting brain?

is there some automatic or blackmagic tool for creating eclipse project from codeblocks project or from sources and makefiles?

[EDIT] ok, i've managed to compile with Makefile project in Eclipse's CDT.

now i have binary files in projectpath/bin/ (and i don't want to modify the makefile because it's a little mess).

if i use them from shell they works ok. but i i click run button in eclipse "Launch failed. Binary not found."

how can i tell to eclipse to localize correclty the compiled project?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a makefile for it, then Eclipse's CDT's Makefile project option should work just fine.

Comment: it gives me some error on load library. i've added the libfmodex.so in "project properties > c/c++ general > paths and symbols > libraries" but no result..

Comment: the problem is (i think) that the makefile is full of absolute path like ADDONS_LIBS_SHARED = $(shell ls ../../../addons/*/libs/*/lib/$(LIBSPATH)/*.so)

Answer (score 0):

There is a thread in the openframeworks forum that discuses using eclipse as an editor for openframeworks at
http://www.openframeworks.cc/forum/viewtopic.php?t=435

another very cheap solution is using whatever editor you want and use the 
codeblocks commandline mode for compiling your project in a shell

```
codeblocks --build whatever.cbp
```

Comment: thanks for advice. i know that topic but i think it is out-of-date because there are some differences 1)in my eclipse (helios) like build target view  and 2)in latest makefile $(PWD). "codeblocks --build" does not permit debug, i think